# Autocomplete in cascading - error [object Object] or not selected word

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have an autocomplete input box, and now I want to get the selected autocomplete entry and send it via a GET request.

When I select one of the autocomplete options, my code only gets the text that I typed, not what I selected. For example: I type "TE" in the input box, and the autocomplete dropdown has "TEST" and "TESTS". Then when I select "TEST" from that list, I only manage to get the "TE" value that I typed, and not the "TEST" that I selected.

If I do this:

```
var ultimo = $('#pais').val();
```

it does not return the selected word, but what I typed. The URL that I make from it becomes:

```
xajax.php?variavel=distritos&q=TE
```

I also tried:

```
var ultimo = $('#pais').val(ui.item.value);
```

But it returns "[object Object]" and not the selected value, and so I get on the URL:

```
xajax.php?variavel=distritos&q=[object Object]
```

I need to get the URL as:

```
xajax.php?variavel=distritos&q=TEST
```

Here is my code (also: http://apoiarmais.com/teste/paises.php):

```
$(function () {
    var paises = [
"Afeganistão","África do Sul","Albânia","Alemanha","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antártida","Antígua e Barbuda","Antilhas Holandesas","Arábia Saudita","Argélia","Argentina","Armênia","Aruba","Austrália","Áustria","Azerbaijão","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Bélgica","Belize","Benin","Bermudas","Bolívia","Bósnia-Herzegovina","Botsuana","Brasil","Brunei","Bulgária","Burquina Faso","Burundi","Butão","Cabo Verde","Camboja","Canadá","Casaquistão","Catar","Chade","Chile","China","Chipre","Cingapura","Colômbia","Comores","Congo","Congo-Kinshasa","Coreia do Norte","Coreia do Sul","Costa do Marfim","Costa Rica","Croácia","Cuba","Dinamarca","Djibuti","Dominica","Egito","El Salvador","Emirados Árabes Unidos","Equador","Eritreia","Eslováquia","Eslovênia","Espanha","Estados Unidos","Estônia","Etiópia","Fiji","Filipinas","Finlândia","França","Gabão","Gâmbia","Gana","Geórgia","Geórgia do Sul e Ilhas Sandwich do Sul","Gibraltar","Granada","Grécia","Groênlandia","Guadalupe","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guiana","Guiana Francesa","Guiné","Guiné Bissau","Guiné Equatorial","Haiti","Holanda","Honduras","Hong Kong, Região Admin. Especial da China","Hungria","Iêmen","Ilha Bouvet","Ilha de Man","Ilha Heard e Ilhas McDonald","Ilha Norfolk","Ilhas Aland","Ilhas Caiman","Ilhas Coco","Ilhas Cook","Ilhas Faroe","Ilhas Malvinas","Ilhas Marianas do Norte","Ilhas Marshall","Ilhas Menores Distantes dos Estados Unidos","Ilhas Natal","Ilhas Salomão","Ilhas Turks e Caicos","Ilhas Virgens Britânicas","Ilhas Virgens dos EUA","Índia","Indonésia","Irã","Iraque","Irlanda","Islândia","Israel","Itália","Jamaica","Japão","Jersey","Jordânia","Kuwait","Lesoto","Letônia","Líbano","Libéria","Líbia","Liechtenstein","Lituânia","Luxemburgo","Macau, Região Admin. Especial da China","Macedônia","Madagascar","Malásia","Malawi","Maldivas","Mali","Malta","Marrocos","Martinica","Maurício","Mauritânia","Mayotte","México","Mianmar","Micronésia","Moçambique","Moldávia","Mônaco","Mongólia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Namíbia","Nauru","Nepal","Nicarágua","Níger","Nigéria","Niue","Noruega","Nova Caledônia","Nova Zelândia","Omã","Palau","Panamá","Papua-Nova Guiné","Paquistão","Paraguai","Peru","Pitcairn","Polinésia Francesa","Polônia","Porto Rico","Portugal","Quênia","Quirguistão","Quiribati","Região desconhecida ou inválida","Reino Unido","República Centro-Africana","República Dominicana","República dos Camarões","República Popular Democrática do Laos","República Tcheca","Reunião","Romênia","Ruanda","Rússia","Saara Ocidental","Saint Pierre e Miquelon","Samoa","Samoa Americana","San Marino","Santa Helena","Santa Lúcia","São Bartolomeu","São Cristovão e Nevis","São Martinho","São Tomé e Príncipe","São Vicente e Granadinas","Senegal","Serra Leoa","Sérvia","Sérvia e Montenegro","Seychelles","Síria","Somália","Sri Lanka","Suazilândia","Sudão","Suécia","Suíça","Suriname","Svalbard e Jan Mayen","Tadjiquistão","Tailândia","Taiwan","Tanzânia","Território Britânico do Oceano Índico","Território da Palestina","Territórios Franceses do Sul","Timor Leste","Togo","Tokelau","Tonga","Trinidad e Tobago","Tunísia","Turcomenistão","Turquia","Tuvalu","Ucrânia","Uganda","Uruguai","Uzbequistão","Vanuatu","Vaticano","Venezuela","Vietnã","Wallis e Futuna","Zâmbia","Zimbábue",

    ];
    $("#pais").autocomplete({
        source: paises
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pais').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
            var ultimo = $('#pais').val(toString(ui.item.value));
            var distritos = 'xajax.php?variavel=distritos&q='+ultimo;
            $("#distritos").autocomplete({
                source: distritos
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(pais);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="pais" />
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="distritos" />
    <div id="tagsdistrito"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the selected value and pass it on the URL?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry, but your "question" is unclear.  Please edit it to give more description of what you're trying to achieve and what issues you're experiencing. As it stands this is not a good fit for Stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and in particular the [ask] pages

Comment: @Alexandre i think that what you want to do is get the disctricts from the country you type right? if that is the case you should disable you second input til you have a valid country, then enable your second input to load the districts from the country you choose

Comment: yes... but how do I pass the selected country variable by get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get the selected value:

Use the callback as you currently have it, but don't look at `.val()`. Instead take the value from the `ui` object:

```
$('#pais').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
    var ultimo = ui.item.value;
    // ...etc
```

Or, just listen to the `autocompletechange` event instead of to `autocompleteselect`. Your `autocompleteselect` event triggers *before* the value changes, but `autocompletechange` triggers *after* it:

```
$('#pais').on('autocompletechange', function () {
    var ultimo = $(this).val();
    // ... etc
```

One other remark, not related to your question:

`$(function() { .... })` is short for `$(document).ready(function() {.... })`, so there is no need to call `ready` again, when you are already in the callback function of the first.